# Why adding column in group by increases result of sum()?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, I have a table

| Date | ID | Column2 | Result of count() |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2022 | 1 | Yes | 3 |
| 01-02-2022 | 1 | No | 2 |
| 01-03-2022 | 2 | Yes | 5 |

And when I want to check totals by date I get the same result when I count directly from table1.

`select date, sum(Result of count()) from (select date, count(distinct ID) from table1 group by date) group by date`

Result: 10

But when I add another column in subquery to count by, like this

`select date, sum(Result of count()) from (select date, column2, count(distinct ID) from table1 group by date, column2) group by date`

I get result with more values: 13

How an addition of another column affects the rows counted?

Comment: Please add table definition of `table1` and some data from the same table. Currently it is impossible to tell what's going on

Comment: The issue is that when you apply a group by operation, you are partitioning on some columns. When you do `select date, count(distinct ID) ... group by date`, you are telling the dbms to aggregate on unique date. When you do  `select date, column2, count(distinct ID) ... group by date, column2`, you are telling the dbms to aggregate on unique combination of <date>, <column2>. As a result, you can check that in your second output table, there are no rows that contain the same combination of `<date>, <column2>` more than once, resulting in a result set with more rows. @condexter